# Find current IOPS usage of EBS volume from my application on AWS EC2

Tags: linux, performance, hard-drive, amazon-ebs, iops

I am relatively new to AWS and disk performance. I am trying to figure out how much provisioned IOPS does my application need to perform well.

Currently My PHP and MySQL application is hosted on EC2 instances with simple EBS volumes attached. The monitoring of EBS volumes provides Read throughput and write throughput with some other matrices. How can I find IOPS of my current EBS volume from Read throughput(~ 400 Ops/s) and write throughput(~ 4000 Ops/s) data?

If I go with the unit of operations/second, IOPS reaches about 4.5K, which I think is not a correct one as simple EBS volume is meant to work alright only on 100 IOPS and occationaly few hundred.

Comment: How are you measuring?

Comment: From the monitoring data provided by AWS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From within your application/instance, I'd attempt to trace the output of `iostat` during controlled application runs. Perhaps `iostat -x 1` in a terminal window.

I also like the [collectl utility](http://collectl.sourceforge.net/) for watching this output. [nmon is a good tool](http://nmon.sourceforge.net/pmwiki.php) for this as well.

[Also read through this article](http://blog.scalyr.com/2012/10/16/a-systematic-look-at-ec2-io/)... **[Even Stranger than Expected: a Systematic Look at EC2 I/O](http://blog.scalyr.com/2012/10/16/a-systematic-look-at-ec2-io/)**.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this in cloudwatch

Check for EBS Metrics and choose VolumeWriteOps (Metric Name)

take any sample from the graph

for e.g.

Data-point : 152398 at 2011-02-10T07:54+0000 (Any highest count from the graph)

```
so it means 152398 IOPS for 10 mins intervel
```

calculate this for 1 min

`152398 IOPS / 10 minutes = 15239.8 IOPS/minute`

then calculate this for `60 seconds`

`15239.8 IOPS / 60 seconds = 253.996666667 IOPS/second`

so `253` is your average `IOPS / seconds` for the volume

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a pretty long discussion with AWS support about the same

Adding to what Ramesh wrote

IOPS are to be calculated as the sum of VolumeReadOps + VolumeWriteOps

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-volume-status.html#using_cloudwatch_ebs

If you can afford to keep your tool continuously running try this 
https://www.metricly.com/iops-calculator-for-ebs-volumes